# Vue.js apply checked on a checkbox based on value from Prop

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

**Explaination**

I'm running Vue.js alongside Laravel and only using it for small components at the moment. I have a checkbox which I need the attribute 'checked' to either be true or false depending on the value from the Prop. The prop is being set by Laravel when the component is loaded in.

When the page loads, the checkbox should be checked depending on the value of the prop. So if the prop is set to false, the checkbox should not be selected, if it's true then the it needs to be selected.

Am I right in thinking that Laravel should set the value via a prop and then I should control that by binding `:checked` to that Props value?

**view.blade.php**

```html
<public-toggle status="true"></public-toggle>
```

**PublicToggle.vue**

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <label class="text-xs font-bold uppercase text-grey-700 mr-2"><i class="fa-question-circle fad text-blue-500 text-sm"></i> Public</label>
        <label class="switch">
            <input type="checkbox" v-bind:value="status" v-on:change="updatePublicStatus" v-model="status" v-bind:checked="status">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
const Toast = Swal.mixin({
  toast: true,
  position: 'top-end',
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 3000
})
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            // status: '',
        }
    },
    methods: {
        updatePublicStatus: function() {
            if(this.status == true) {
                Toast.fire({
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Public'
                })
            } else {
                Toast.fire({
                    type: 'success',
                    title: 'Private'
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

If anyone could help me get my head round this, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Is the prop only to be used to pass the *initial* value? That can be done but usually it's preferred for the prop to hold the *current* value. The key difference is what happens when the checkbox is checked/unchecked. Should `PublicToggle` just treat the change as internal state or should it notify the parent component so that the new prop value can be passed?

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following way, in the Laravel (Blade) part:

```
<public-toggle :status="{{$status}}"></public-toggle>
```

And in the VueJS component:

```
data(){
// your data
},
props: ['status'],
```

Remember the CamelCase issue, if the Blade var is something like: 'your-var' in VueJs component will be: 'yourVar'.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Matt Are you not seeing an error in the console when you click the checkbox?

Comment: @skirtle I'm getting two actually! `The data property "status" is already declared as a prop. Use prop default value instead.` and `Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "status"` - I'm not entirely sure how to get the desired result I need.